# React: props has a value at first render afterwards is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-props

```
export const Modal = (props, { farm, id }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();

  console.log("NewId", props.id);

  const initialFieldValues = {
    title: "",
    image: "",
    product: "",
    content: "",
    phone: "",
    email: "",
  };

  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialFieldValues);

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  }

  const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const obj = {
      ...values,
    };
    getFirebase()
      .database()
      .ref(`Users/${props.id}`)
      // .ref(`Users/${newId}`)

      .push(obj, (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // console.log("ID", newId);
      });
  };
```

PARENT COMPONENT

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [id, setId] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);
        userRef.on("value", (snapShot) => {
          setCurrentUser({ key: snapShot.key, ...snapShot.val() });
        });
        // }
      }
      if (setCurrentUser(userAuth)) {
      } else if (!userAuth && typeof window !== "undefined") {
        return null;
      }
      const id = userAuth.uid;
      setId(id);
    });
  <>
      <Modal id={id} />
    </>;
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

When i console.log it here .ref(`Users/${props.id}`) it's undefined.

This is how my console looks like:

12modal.jsx:12 'NewId' fRHyyzzEotPpIGUkkqJkKQnrTOF2

12modal.jsx:12 'NewId' undefined

it comes one time with the ID and 12 times undifiend.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can't change a props values, and if props.id is a state(i.e. `const [id, setId] = React.useState(initial value)`) then you can change id only by setId which is not received by child, so i think parent might be causing this issue.

Comment: I think you are right, it makes more sense this way. I added the parent component as well to this post, still not sure how to fix it

Comment: parent component is incomplete, and you are setting id `setId` in unsubscribe which is return of useEffect(similar to destructor i.e. it will be executed at the end).